# Array content is "undefined" instead of an image file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My function stores the image from a Google Drive folder in an array, and then selects a random one. However, it seems to lose the the image type and I can't work on it anymore. If there is no more images, it use ones from another folder.

```
function sendRandomPic()
{
    var files = getFolders("Projet").getFiles();
    var results = [];

    // Scan each file to see if it matches any of our filters.
    while (files.hasNext())
    {
      //stock all images
      results.push(files.next());
    }
    // Select a random file 
    if (results.length == 0)
    {
      var file = getFolders("BOT").getFiles().next();
    }
    else 
    {
      var file = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)+1];
      Logger.log(typeof file);
    }
    return file
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you expect from the line `var file = results[Math.floor(Math.random() * results.length)+1];`?

Comment: it's should select a random image stored in the array Results[]

Comment: Okay the +1 was messing everything up..
Thank you !

Comment: Add a few more logs, specially result.length and the random resulting value and see if you get a match

Comment: Off-by-1 because JavaScript array indices start at 0 and not 1. Removing that `+1` should let you properly access the contents of `results`